# Cannot connect to samba member server as local user a few days after AD join and SSSD

Tags: active-directory, samba4, sssd

Edit: I tried to simplify the question:

=========================================================================
How can I enable a local (linux/samba) user to access a samba share (member server) besides the AD-users, which already have access?

The problem is that my samba always asks the DC for user authentication and never tries to authenticate the user using passwd/smbpasswd.

=========================================================================

Here is the old, long question:

i managed to set up a Samba 4 server on Ubuntu 18.04.

My steps:

- Drive is mounted with "user_xattr acl"
- Hostname is set to e.g. myserver
- ipv6 is disabled
- the ipv4 static ip is set correctly with netplan
- the only entry in /etc/hosts is "127.0.0.1       localhost"
- timesync is configured and working
- installed: krb5-user samba sssd sssd-tools
- created an AD Group (edit: on the Windows Server 2008 DC) e. g. g_fileserver_rw and joined the AD accounts to the group
- **/etc/krb5.conf**

  ```
  [libdefaults]
     default_realm = INTDOM.TLD
     ticket_lifetime = 24h #
     renew_lifetime = 7d
  # The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
     kdc_timesync = 1
     ccache_type = 4
     forwardable = true
     proxiable = true
  # The following libdefaults parameters are only for Heimdal Kerberos.
     fcc-mit-ticketflags = true
  [realms]
  [domain_realm]
     .intdom.tld = INTDOM.TLD
     intdom.tld = INTDOM.TLD
  ```

  I have a comprehension question here:
  Are the parameters "kdc_timesync, ccache_type, forwardable, proxiable, fcc-mit-ticketflags" necessary or adverse here?
- **/etc/sssd/sssd.conf**, mode 600

  ```
  [sssd]
  services = nss, pam
  config_file_version = 2
  domains = MC.DE

  [domain/MC.DE]
  id_provider = ad
  access_provider = ad

  # edit: this is actually not used
  override_homedir = /home/%d/%u

  # edit: I need this, performance not an issue in my env.
  enumerate = true
  ```
- **/etc/nsswitch.conf**

  ```
  passwd:         compat systemd sss
  group:          compat systemd sss
  shadow:         compat sss
  gshadow:        files

  hosts:          files dns
  networks:       files

  protocols:      db files
  services:       db files sss
  ethers:         db files
  rpc:            db files

  netgroup:       nis sss
  sudoers:        files sss
  ```
- Domain join with ´net ads join -U admin@INTDOM.TLD´ was successfull
- ´getent passwd´ and ´getent group´ list local and domain users respectively groups
- I added a local user (e.g. lu) with this command:
  ´adduser --home /dev/null --shell /bin/true --gecos "" lu´
- then I created a samba user with
  ´smbpasswd lu´ using the same password
- I set up the rights on the shares like that (if you wonder that group has more rights than user, see ´acl group control = yes´ entry in smb.conf below):

  ```
  chown -R lu:@g_fileserver_rw@INTDOM.TLD /sambashare/One
  chown -R lu:@g_fileserver_rw@INTDOM.TLD /sambashare/Two
  chmod u-w,g+w,o-rwx /sambashare/One
  chmod g+w,o-rwx /sambashare/Two
  ```
- **/etc/samba/smb.conf**

  ```
  [global]
     workgroup = INTERNAL
  # Entries recommended in Ubuntu-Wiki:
          log level = 0
          client signing = yes
          client use spnego = yes
          kerberos method = secrets and keytab
          realm = INTDOM.TLD
          security = ads
  # End of Ubuntu-Wiki-entries
  # My entries
  restrict anonymous = 2
  acl group control = yes
  inherit acls = yes
  inherit owner = yes
  inherit permissions = yes
  vfs objects = acl_xattr
  deadtime = 15
  store dos attributes = yes
  domain master = no
  local master = no
  preferred master = no
  os level = 0
  idmap config * : backend = tdb
  idmap config * : range = 1000-199999
  idmap config MC.DE : backend = sss
  idmap config MC.DE : range = 200000-2000200000
  # End of my entries
     server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
     wins server = <WINS-Server IP Address>
     dns proxy = no
     log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
     max log size = 1000
     syslog = 0
     panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
     server role = member server
     passdb backend = tdbsam
     obey pam restrictions = yes
     passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
     passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
     map to guest = bad user
  [One]
          path = /sambashare/One
          valid users = "lu", @g_fileserver_rw@INTDOM.TLD
          create mask = 570
          directory mask = 570
          writeable = no
          write list = @g_fileserver_rw@INTDOM.TLD
  [Two]
          path = /sambashare/Two
          valid users = "lu", @g_fileserver_rw@INTDOM.TLD
          create mask = 770
          directory mask = 770
          writeable = yes
  ```

For a week all was working normal, but now the local user "lu" can no longer access the shares. The domain users can access the shares normally. The local rights are still the same: ´drwxrwx---+´ on directories  and ´-r-xrwx---+´ for lu:g_fileserver_rw@INTDOM.TLD.

Can someone tell me how to enable the local user to access the shares again?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was my fault. The config is actually working and it did not stop working after a few days, but I was rather dumb to make this assumption as I saw problems with other machines.
It still worked on the machines I tested it first.

Windows machines, which had an altered security policy (different from the default) could not connect using a local account.

The setting is here:

Under "Security Options" in secpol.msc:

"Network security: LAN Manager authentication level"

it started to work, as soon as I set it to:

"Send NTLMv2 response only"

I'm sorry that I wasted your time.

A mod can remove my question and answer all together, if he considers so.